# Programmatically change table in Radgrid - NeedDataSource doesn't fire on Rebind()

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid

I need to point a radgrid to the table selected in a dropdownlist. So I have the selectedIndexChanged event of the dropdownList calling the Rebind() which should fire the radgrid NeedDataSource event where I set the datasource commands. But it does not fire!

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        RadGrid1.DataSource=null;
        Label1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text; //just for debugging
        RadGrid1.Rebind();

    }
}

protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    string tableInUse = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
    Label2.Text = "NeedDataSource has been fired"; //just for debugging
    RadGrid1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
    SqlDataSource1.DeleteCommand = "DELETE FROM [" + tableInUse + "] .....";
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [" + tableInUse + "] ORDER BY [Code]";
    SqlDataSource1.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE [" + tableInUse + "] SET ....";

}
```

and the markup:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" Culture="it-IT" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource">
            <MasterTableView DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            </MasterTableView>
        </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Not sure if this is the correct way to change the database table associated to a radgrid but at least the NeedDatasource event should get fired. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't set both the DataSourceID and DataSource parameter; it's not firing because it has a DataSourceID set to a data source control, and just gets what it needs from there.  You would have to clear that too.  But instead, it may make sense to react to the events on the datasource and change what you want from there (Selecting, Updating, etc.)

Comment: Thats brilliant! Thank you for the advices. You were absolutely correct. This solved my problem.